# HTML & CSS: Align text line to bottom center of div

Tags: html, css, layout, center

I would like to set a specific layout for my divs. These divs contain summaries (texts about 500 chars long) and I would like that after the text, on the bottom edge of my boxes, to have a line containing something like `Link to additional information : *link*`.

Here's an ascii layout-art for you guys to understand what I mean:

---

Here is some text blablablablablablablab lablablablablablablablablablablabla  gfff ff f blablablablablablablablablablablablabla  blablablablablablablablablablablablabla  ff f ffff blablablablablablablablablablab lablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablab  ff lablablablablablablablablablablablablab lablablablablablablablablabla blablablablablabla blablablablablabla blablablablablablablabla blablablablablablablabla blablablablablablablabla

```
               Link to additional information here : *link*.
```

---

I want the last line to be centered. My layout uses percentage, therefore I cannot use absolute positioning. It should be able to move if the window gets resized.

Here is the CSS of the div:

```
float: left;
width: 91.5%;
min-width: 825px;
height: 120px;
text-align: left;
z-index: 1;
border:solid 1px #19365D;
background-image:url('images/NiceBackgroundDude.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
margin-left:3.7%;
margin-right:3.7%;
padding-left:0.5%;
padding-right:0.5%;
```

---

**EDIT:** If forgot to tell, those Divs are DOM elements (aka they are generated everytime the page is loaded) and the link is in a separate tag in the XML file. therefore, if there is something I could do like:

```html
<div class="summarydiv"> summary from xml</div><br>
<div class="centerlink">link line and link from xml</div>
```

Comment: Solved! Will leave this here for future references. Have a good day everyone!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I really like divs because you never know when you may want to style blocks differently, so this is how I would do it:

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div>Here is some text........</div>
   <div class="link"><a href="#">Link to additional information</a></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.parent {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    width: 91.5%;
    min-width: 825px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1;
    border:solid 1px #19365D;
    background-image:url('images/NiceBackgroundDude.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-left:3.7%;
    margin-right:3.7%;
    padding-left:0.5%;
    padding-right:0.5%;
}

.link {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and finally a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75yyH/4/) showing it in action!

Comment: Dear friend, thank you for the answer, it is really appreciated. Have a good week-end! Cheers!

Comment: Hey man if you are still here, i tried using it without the position:relative in the parent div, and all the links would appear on the bottom of the webpage all over the other. How comes modifying the parent dive positioning only modifies the child divs positioning on the layout? while this is a little out of subject, i would like to understand the position: relative tag properly, i don't really understand from the examples i've seen so far :/

Answer (score 4):

You could play a bit with position and margins

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:50%;
margin-left: -50%;
```

positioning at left 50% will start from the vertical axis of your container. Negative margin to the left will center the inner div.

Comment: I think `transform: translateX(-50%)` is a better option compared to margin-left:-50%; it works for smaller elements.

Comment: I got used to resorting to margin-left by mimicyng some bootstrap2 dialog examples, nowadays I believe it was just a random choice and not a best practice whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the last line into an `<span>` element, set the element style to

```
width: auto;
text-align: center;
```

that should do the job

Comment: Thanks for the width: auto; i didn't know you could do that! Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

You can also put htat last line in its own div & set the bottom margin to zero with an !important.

Answer (score 0):

[`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) worked for me. Here's how I did:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 91.5%;
  min-width: 825px;
  height: 120px;
  border: solid 1px #19365D;
}

.item {
  width: auto;
  /* Grow to fill available space */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.summary {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.link {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  /* Make the flexbox items aligned vertically at the bottom */
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item summary">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibu
  </div>
  <div class="item link">
    <a href="#">Link to additional information</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works for me:

```
.align-bottom-center {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To align the div to the center, Just use below css:

```
.alignCenter{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

<div class="alignCenter"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

To align to the bottom center, you can use the below code:

```
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60% 20% 0% 20%;
```